# Detect/listen when visible price range changed in lightweight-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightweight-charts

So the [timeScale](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/master/docs/time-scale.md) in [lightweight-chart](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts) has a way to detect when visible time range is being updated (through `subscribeVisibleTimeRangeChange`).

My question, is there a similar way to **detect/listen** when visible price range changed? Gone through the documentation for a bit but couldn't find anything close.

We have a use case where we wanna adjust the price line in area chart when **min/max price** range changes.

Feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No, `lightweight-charts` doesn't have such feature yet. You can create a feature request for that (but please look at https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/621 first, there you can find a discussion why there is still no getters/setters for price range, I think it might be related to events too).

> We have a use case where we wanna adjust the price line in area chart when min/max price range changes.

You can try to do some hacks with overriding `autoscaleInfoProvider` of the series, but I can't tell you for sure whether it will work for you or not.